# How to convert my hybris project to docker image

Tags: docker, sap-commerce-cloud

I built a project. It is an electronic store but I changed some parts.

I used installer. I used b2c acc.

Now, I want to make this project as a docker.

So, without installing any ant, jdk or another thing, this image will be installed and will be able to run.

I found this tutorial

https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanlehmann/hybris-base-image/

but I don't know what to do.

I manually pulled the image.

```
# run installer with b2c recipe
./install.sh -r b2c_acc_plus

# create production artifacts
cd ../hybris/bin/platform
. ./setantenv.sh
ant clean all production

# create Dockerfile
cd ../../..
mkdir docker
mv hybris/temp/hybris/hybrisServer/hybrisServer*.zip docker/
cd docker
echo "FROM stefanlehmann/hybris-base-image:latest
ENV PLATFORM_HOME=\$HYBRIS_HOME/bin/platform
ENV PATH=\$PLATFORM_HOME:\$PATH
COPY hybrisServer*.zip $HYBRIS_HOME" >> Dockerfile
cat Dockerfile
```

so after i pull image, i will do only those parts?:

```
# create Dockerfile
cd ../../..
mkdir docker
mv hybris/temp/hybris/hybrisServer/hybrisServer*.zip docker/
cd docker
echo "FROM stefanlehmann/hybris-base-image:latest
ENV PLATFORM_HOME=\$HYBRIS_HOME/bin/platform
ENV PATH=\$PLATFORM_HOME:\$PATH
COPY hybrisServer*.zip $HYBRIS_HOME" >> Dockerfile
cat Dockerfile
```

or you can suggest another image.

Answer (score -2):

if you have the image already downloaded , you can run it using

```
docker run -d -p 9001:9001 -p 9002:9002 IMAGEID/IMAGENAME
```

You can follow this link for more details :https://github.com/jokumar/DockerHybris